# What is the use of the fields paramater while creating a google drive folder using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api

In the below code I am trying to create a google drive folder via the [Google API Node.js client](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client)

```
var fileMetadata = {
  'name' : 'Project plan',
  'mimeType' : 'application/vnd.google-apps.drive-sdk'
};

// what is fields and resource key being used
drive.files.create({
   resource: fileMetadata,
   fields: 'id' 
}, function(err, file) {
  if(err) {
    // Handle error
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log('File Id: ', file.id);
  }
});
```

What does the `fields: id` parameter represent?

Answer (score 0):

The response from the REST API will only include the `fields` you specify

https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/performance

> **Request for a partial response**: The following request for this same
>   resource uses the fields parameter to significantly reduce the amount
>   of data returned.
>
> `https://www.googleapis.com/demo/v1?key=YOUR-API-KEY&fields=kind,items(title,characteristics/length)`

Although `fields` is not documented in the [client API](https://google.github.io/google-api-nodejs-client/8.0.0/drive_.html), any parameters that are not locally dealt with in the client are [forwarded through in the HTTP request.](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/lib/apirequest.js#L167-L180)